# Can my network use Ubuntu Openstack?

Tags: networking, server, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I have a small network of computers,
I am migrating from Arch Linux to Ubuntu's OpenStack Platform for usability reasons.
The reason I am asking is because of the following:

*Installing Ubuntu OpenStack requires at least seven machines with two disks, two of which have two network interfaces (NICs). Install Ubuntu Server on one of the machines with two interfaces.*

I have two systems, one of which I can and hopefully will host six virtual machines and will form the cluster, and the other I am planning to be the cluster controller.

I am having numerous issues meeting the prerequisites of using the ubuntu openstack platform, namely:

- Network Configuration and Setup
- Actually, I don't know anything about OpenStack.

Could someone give me a walkthrough on how to meet the requirements of this situation with the following resources:

> **Computer 1 - The (*Hopefully it works*) Virtualised Cluster**
>
> Intel Core i7 - 3770K.
>
> 16GB of physical memory, 8GB virtual (swap).
>
> 6+ KVM Virtual Machines (Presumably using all available resources).
>
> Two NIC's.
>
> Ubuntu Server as VM Host.

Now is the controller.

> **Computer 2 - OpenStack Controller**
>
> 4GB RAM and Swap
>
> Two NIC's
>
> A new-*ish* Intel Pentium (The one a bit better than a late Core 2 Duo)

I can't really afford any more systems as I am on a High School student's income, is there a way to make this work? I am not deleting my Arch partition until I know for sure. I am really limited by my systems and the documentation for the networking setup seems oddly scarce. Is anyone able to assist me on installation? Also, I don't know how to configure libvirt to allow me to network like this, will I need to host DHCP on one of my 'servers' or can I still rely on my good little Netgear router (DGND4000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can build and deploy OpenStack on Ubuntu:

1. (easiest) use the OpenStack Autopilot. As you noticed, currently this requires 7 machines.
2. Juju.  You can use Juju to deploy and configure OpenStack services. You need to install MAAS and Juju, but you do not need to know about OpenStack as much.
3. (hardest) Apt. follow the installation guide for Ubuntu on OpenStack.org, and build your configuration manually. You will need to learn quite a bit about OpenStack.

All three solutions require hardware, because OpenStack is infrastructure, and while it can be faked to test patches, OpenStack with almost no hardware is... hardly useful.

If you want to test OpenStack in the small scale, not for production, I recommend for now you use:

```
apt-get install openstack
```

and try the single system cloud configuration you can build there. In alternative, you can try DevStack, which also gives you a (hardly realistic) cloud packed into one box.

Finally, I hear the next beta of the OpenStack Autopilot may require less hardware resources for non-HA configurations. You may want to wait a few weeks until that's out and see if we managed to bring the bar low enough for you - you may still need a third machine, but that would be all.